# How to get the latest record by date and not the first from a table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my query i get the first record i olje table when i group by frl_nr. There are many records with the same frl_nr i the olje table. I want to get the latest record from the olje table by date column. Her is my search string:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM frl_sok 
          INNER JOIN olje ON frl_sok.id_nr = olje.id_nr 
        WHERE frl_sok.kunde_nr = '$kunde' 
           AND frl_sok.jobb_nr = '$jobb_nr' 
        GROUP BY frl_sok.frl_nr DESC";
```

What is the solution?

[Both of my tables are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwLJj.png)

Comment: could you add the tables and maybe also some data for the tables. It is impossible to guess which column is a Datetime column. Also this **DESC** doesn't work at that position, it has be be woth an ORDER BY

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should use row_number() rather than trying to group by.

Try this:

```
select * from (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() over (partion by frl_sok.frl_nr order by date desc) rn
    FROM frl_sok 
    INNER JOIN olje ON frl_sok.id_nr = olje.id_nr 
    WHERE frl_sok.kunde_nr = '$kunde' 
    AND frl_sok.jobb_nr = '$jobb_nr' 
) q where rn=1"
```

Comment: You really have to help us out here with a little more information. If it "doesnt work" are you getting an error, wrong results, or what? I'm only guessing at how you want to partition and sort the data as you don't have enough information in your question.

Comment: I would also try the query directly in the workbench and try and resolve that first before worrying about how to pass the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with and it works.

$sql = "SELECT  a.id_nr, a.frl_nr, a.maskin_id, a.tilstand_olje, b.date FROM frl_sok a INNER JOIN olje b ON a.id_nr = b.id_nr INNER JOIN (SELECT  id_nr, MAX(date) Max_Date FROM    olje GROUP BY id_nr) c ON  b.id_nr = c.id_nr AND b.date = c.Max_date WHERE a.kunde_nr = '$kunde' AND a.jobb_nr = '$jobb_nr'";